# Delay on a MessageBox in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

The question is about Visual Studio in a project in the Windows Form.

Is it possible to place a Delay on a MessageBox after pressing a button? I'm trying that when someone uses the program and press the "OK" button, the program wouldn't show the message instantly, rather it would take some seconds to show the message.

If there's no option to delay a Message Box, if its possible what recommendation would you recommend me instead of using a Message Box for the button.

Comment: [Task.Delay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: It works! Thank you Kenneth K. :)

Comment: After the MessageBox returns, do std::this_thread::sleep_for(...) or do you want the message box to remain on the screen? In that case you may need to write your own message box.